# AttributeError: _convert in enum.py is not letting Kernel connect

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda, anaconda3, jupyter-irkernel

After updating to Notebook 7, Kernel is unable to connect - the message being "connection failed. connection to the notebook server could not be established. the notebook will continue trying to reconnect."

The Error in Prompt is -

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\enum.py", line 784, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: _convert
```

I have tried all the below but nothing seems to be working-

1. Uninstall & re-install Ananconda.
2. Replacing enum.py with the one here -"https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/19a1e1eb86115db66c1faae5927f87e3a12692fc#diff-8a31d1a570139c8bd71a401e207e9a76c2513f317bd7d9ca2c3513034625698a".
3. Tried this too -"https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-fix-anaconda-jupyter-notebook-kernel-error/".
4. Tried this too -"[Issue connecting to the Kernel in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326053/issue-connecting-to-the-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook)".

Here is [enum.py](https://cbre-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/r/personal/renu_sharma_cbre_com/Documents/enum.py?csf=1&web=1&e=845H1X) I have.

Any help is highly appreciated,
Thanks